# Reference for etale cohomology with compact support for algebraic varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, schemes, etale-cohomology

I've followed a course about basics of Etale Cohomology last year which pratically covered the first 13 chapters of the great notes by Milne:Lectures on Etale Cohomology.

Now,I'd need to learn something about cohomology with compact support:where could I find a detailed reference(I feel like that part is not so clear in Milne notes)?

I'm in particular interested to find out how it is obtained a  replacement in this context of the standard Leray Spectral Sequence and the formula which describes the higher direct image in terms of   the cohomology of the sheaf restrctited to the fibers.

Comment: Section 18 of Milne's notes is pretty good in my opinion. What kind of details are you interested in?

Comment: The canonical references are section IV.5 of Arcata in SGA $4\frac12$, and of course exposé XVII ‘Cohomologie à supports propres’ of SGA 4 for full detail.